# Why is my function not giving the role discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
  let targetUser = message.mentions.members.first();
  targetUser.roles.add("772871120550363176");

  message.channel.send(targetUser + "is muted !unmute <@> to unmute the user!");
}
```

I dont know why this doesnt work

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question is very open-ended and is hard to answer. Do you have any idea why it might not be working

Comment: Hey @Levi_OP im running it as a command and i would like it to give a role that is not able to talk the role id is correct i checked i googled the web all day and it should work all my other commands are working as intended ;D

Comment: do you get any error messages?

Comment: Are you sure that snippet is being executed?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see more of the code.

Comment: I know that this command is the fault targetUser.roles.add("772834754449244170"); @Levi_OP it gives the error Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run your code on my server and it works fine. So I suggest you check your role id for errors. Here is the code I ran, if it helps.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'your token here';
const PREFIX = '$';

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
})

bot.on('message', message =>{
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)||message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'welcome'){
        if (message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
          let targetUser = message.mentions.members.first();
          targetUser.roles.add("role id");

          message.channel.send(targetUser + "is muted !unmute <@> to unmute the user!");
        }
    }
})

bot.login(token);
```

This is the command I ran:

```
$welcome @user
```

This is my console after running:

```
C:\Users\Rak\Desktop\Bot>node .
Bot is online!
^C
C:\Users\Rak\Desktop\Bot>
```

This is the bot's reply:

```
768442726483590155is muted !unmute <@> to unmute the user!
```

My account got the role I wanted.